# How to configure JBoss 6 with custom auth-method

Tags: java, jboss5.x, jboss6.x

Perhaps I could ask you if you guys if you could help me out how to configure JBoss 6 with a custom auth-method?
We are moving from JBoss 5 to JBoss 6.
In 5 we got a web.xml with this login-tag

```
<login-config>
<auth-method>OURSSO</auth-method>
<realm-name>oursso</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

And a jboss-app.xml

```
<security-domain>oursso</security-domain>
```

And in login-config.xml

```
<application-policy name="oursso">
<authentication>
<login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule" flag="sufficient">
<module-option name="usersProperties">props/mycomp-users.properties</module-option>
<module-option name="rolesProperties">props/mycomp-roles.properties</module-option>
<module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity">anonymous</module-option>
</login-module>
<login-module code="rsa.ps.ct.jboss.jaas.OURSSOServerLoginModule" flag="required">
<module-option name="connectionProvider">rsa.access.manager:type=Service,name=RuntimeAPIClient</module-option>
</login-module>
<login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.RoleMappingLoginModule" flag="optional">
<module-option name="rolesProperties">props/mycomp-rolemapping-roles.properties</module-option>
<module-option name="replaceRole">true</module-option>
</login-module>
</authentication>
</application-policy>
```

And in war-deployers-jboss-beans.xml

```
<property name="authenticators">
<map class="java.util.Properties" keyClass="java.lang.String" valueClass="java.lang.String">
<entry>
<key>BASIC</key>
<value>org.apache.catalina.authenticator.BasicAuthenticator</value>
</entry>

...

<entry>
<key>OURSSO</key>
<value>com.mycomp.OurssoAuthenticator</value>
</entry>
</map>         
</property>
```

It seems like the auth-method in web.xml must match a key in war-deployers-jboss-beans.xml. How is the same accomplish in JBoss 6?

Best regards

Fredrik

Comment: Any progress in this? I'm also interested..

Comment: Hello, not yet acctually. But I have got some advise from a friend a couple of weeks ago, that I hope I will get time to try out asap. Unfortenately we, our complete team, had to switch focus and fix some issue. Best regards and merry christmas.

Answer (score 0):

I added these to my standalone-full.xml

```
<security-domain name="my-security-domain" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule" flag="required">
            <module-option name="usersProperties" value="file://${jboss.server.config.dir}/users.properties"/>
            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="file://${jboss.server.config.dir}/roles.properties"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

In the file users.properties

```
123=qwe
456=asd
```

In the file roles.properties

```
123=role.A,role.B
456=role.B
```

In one of my beans in the server I annotate it with

```
@Stateless

@SecurityDomain("my-security-domain")
@RolesAllowed("role.A")
public class SecureStatelessBean extends SecureReturnAString implements SecureStatelessBeanLocal, SecureStatelessBeanRemote
{
 ...
```

In my web-application (running in the same server) I lookup the bean and login with this code

```
@EJB(lookup = "java:global/ejbtest-app/ejbtest-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/SecureStatelessBean!se.albinoni.ejbtest.stateless.SecureStatelessBeanRemote")
private SecureStatelessBeanRemote secureStatelessBeanRemote;

...

private static SecurityClient getClientLogin() throws Exception
{
    final SecurityClient client = SecurityClientFactory.getSecurityClient();
    client.setSimple("123", "qwe");
    return client;
}

...

SecurityClient client = getClientLogin();
client.login();

secureStatelessBeanRemote.someMethod();
```

Think that was it.
But I still have not found out how to do the same from a remote standalone app.